# Calculating matrices on CPU takes up most of the frame time

Tags: ios, swift, macos, opengl-es, metal

I am writing a simple engine for a simple game, so far I enjoy my little hobby project but the game grew and it now has roughly 800 of game objects at a time in a scene.

Every object, just like in Unity, has a transform component that calculates transformation matrix when the component is initialized. I started to notice that with 800 objects it takes 5.4 milliseconds just to update each matrix (for example if every object has moved) without any additional components or anything else.

I use GLKit math library, which for some reason faster than using native simd types. using simd types triples the time of calculation

here is a pice of code that runs it

```
    let Translation : GLKMatrix4 = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(position.x, position.y, position.z)
    let Scale : GLKMatrix4 = GLKMatrix4MakeScale(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z)
    let Rotation : GLKMatrix4 = GLKMatrix4MakeRotationFromEulerVector(rotation)
    
    //Produce model matrix
    let SRT = GLKMatrix4Multiply(Translation, GLKMatrix4Multiply(Rotation, Scale))
```

Question: I am looking for a way to optimize this so I can use more game objects. and utilize more components on my objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple bottlenecks in your program.

1. Optimise your frame dependencies to avoid stalls as much as possible, e.g. by precomputing frame data on CPU. [This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/synchronization/synchronizing_cpu_and_gpu_work) is a good resource to learn about this technique.
2. Make sure that all matrices are stored in one MTLBuffer which is indexed from your vertex stage
3. On Apple silicon and iOS use MTLResourceStorageModeShared
4. If you really want to scale to tens of thousands of objects, then compute your matrices in a compute shader to store them in an MTLBuffer. Then, use indirect rendering to issue your draw calls.
5. In general, learn about [AZDO](https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1020791/Approaching-Zero-Driver-Overhead-in).

Learn about compute shaders: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/basic_tasks_and_concepts/performing_calculations_on_a_gpu

Learn about indirect rendering:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/indirect_command_buffers

Comment: I thought I about computing all matrices on gpu but question arises regarding copying from non continues memory chunks to the buffer on each frame. However particle system I do run on gpu since I keep a particle component in one place so it is easy to manage the buffer posed to random location chunks of transformation component on different objects.

Comment: But indirect commands is not directly related to my problem I just tried it, and man... command encoding used totactually take time, now since I don't do it on each render pass I save a lot of time thanks for pointing it out!